# Access denied when try to create or view directory, asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have an Asp.net application that handles the function of creating a directory and then viewing that directory (on the network).

```
  Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo (Me.lblPath.Text)
  di.Create()
  Process.Start(Me.lblPath.Text)
```

Both creating and viewing the directory work perfectly from Visual Studio... but when I run the compiled asp.net application it shows me "access denied" in both cases.

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access denied]

The folder where the subdirectories are created is on the network and is shared for everyone.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you check, the folder probably was created. It really depends on the user you using to run the application pool.

However, then 2nd part?

```
 Process.Start(Me.lblPath.Text)
```

That is not allowed anymore. Server running process (such as IIS) are in general not allowed to shell launch system apps.

So, you can get your code to create the folders. But, IIS is a service, and such running services as a general rule can't start (shell) execute things like windows explorer in this case.

You might try giving the application pool user rights to do this, but from what I can tell, by default, running IIS services, that service can't start such programs.

You can CERTAINLY do this on your development computer, since you running VS, and it runs + launches IIS express as a context as you the super user and owner of that computer.

but, on a real server, running IIS? Nope, in general this is not allowed. Quite sure this hole was plugged around 2008. In think in server 2012, you COULD set security to make this work (I believe some kind of rights to a console_0 user.

but, after 2012, even that option was removed.

So, such code? Yes, it will work during deployment on your development computer. but a server system, running IIS is locked down, and to my knowledge, you can't execute or run such processes.

Put in a try/catch, and send the error out to a extra text box on that page - you see the web does generate a error.